# PHP: Split results of query into 2 columns

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to load contacts from a query, Whilst I have found ways to split by the amount of rows I want the result to be split into two columns as below as well as them being a sort of clickable button.Is it possible to display the query results as described below by the use of HTML or by the query itself? :

```
Contacts
------------------------------
Albert Smith   | Ben Marshall
Benjamin Jones | Chris Jones
```

I have tried the code below

```
<? 
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($records);
echo "<div id='column1'>";
$i = 0;
while ($d = mysql_fetch_object($records)) {
  echo $d->name;
  $i++;

  if ($i == floor($rowcount / 2)) {
      echo "</div><div id='colums2'>";
  }
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

But this splits the columns by reaching half of the results in 1 column and the rest in another column

Albert Smith | Benjamin Jones

Ben Marshall | Chris Jones

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Put here some test datas and your query or what have you tried till now

Comment: Have you tried using subqueries and filtering by odd and even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible by query itself.
You must parse the result with an html `<table>`, every two results make a new `<tr>` and double `<td>`

Comment: It is possible to achieve those results by SQL but I'm agree with you, using a table is more efficient.

Comment: So using php I parse the result and whenever the number is divisble by 2 a new table is created for the following sets?

Comment: `if ($i % 2 == 0 && $i != count($records)) {
      // do ur thing
  }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are conversant with coding:
 Check this algorithm

1. get results
2. declare an even/odd check variable
3. loop through your result-set
4. List item

   increment the counter in each loop

   ii. check counter value in the loop

   - iii. if counter variable value is even give it a different class
   - To make them a clickable button, you can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as  (ie. give an  tag the style of a button)

Let me know on how it works out.
 Have fun coding.

Comment: Altough I am close to what I need, Im having a bit of trouble, the columns are not being placed as they should for some reason the even column is being put in a new row and in the 2 columns of that row

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot of the same. It will be helpful

Comment: Image isn't loading